# VSE's transform strip crops the image

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there any way to prevent VSE's transform strip from cropping the image?

If you have an image that is larger than the video format like this :

[image]

When you use a scale of 1 for the image, it looks like this (which is the expected output) :

[image]

But then, when I use the transform strip to move it around, rotate or scale, I notice that all the parts of the image that are beyond the frame get cropped :

[image]

Is there any option that may allow to prevent this?

This doesn't happen when we use the transform options of the strip itself and I can use that if all I wanted was position the image and stuff but there are some cases where one have to use the transform strip and this cropping just makes it impossible.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The transform strip is just working with the final data, not the original. You have to use the source strip’s options if you want to get the original data back.

Comment: This is the answer I was afraid of but I really don't think that's how it's supposed to be. A transform strip should not crop the image.

Comment: The transform strip isn’t cropping the image. The image gets cropped when it gets fed to the transform strip. Blender does not preserve “off screen“ strip data when it’s fed into the next strip up.

Comment: I understand. That makes sense too. I just wish there would be an exception for the transform strip. It's too bad, addons like VSE transform Tools allows to stabilize footage right inside VSE but because of this cropping thing, I have to do everything in the compositor.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention your Blender version. In the recent versions (from 2.9 on) you can transform (scale, rotate, move) a movie strip without adding a transform strip. Just change the Strip properties; see attached image

[[image: Transform panel of movie strip (from version 2.9 on)1]

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using 3.0. But I am mentioning the transform properties of the strip on the last paragraph of my question. Thanks for the answer tho.